# Exception trying to delete search result object

Tags: ios, core-data, uisearchbar

My app has a table view with sections, populated from a core data entity. I have included a search bar. When using the search bar, the search result objects are shown under a new section. Please see the two screenshots, first the normal table view with sections, second the table view with search results objects:

[image]
[image]

The problem is at trying to delete the search result object using the default commiEditingStyle method. With the help from other more expert SO users, I have included there two if clauses, one for deleting an object when the subject is a search result object, and the second if for deleting an object from the normal table view.
Here is the method code so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        [self.searchResults removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
            ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When deleting an object from the normal table view (first image) there is no issue. But trying to delete a search result object (second image), the app crash showing following exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd17b060'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aab5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b48903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9b90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9b4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   To-Do Pro Light                     0x00004eda -[ToDoItemsTableViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 298
    6   UIKit                               0x0068cba3 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 107
    7   UIKit                               0x0080c695 -[UITableViewCell _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 70
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01840874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x0059e0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x0059e04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x006960c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x00696484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x00695733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x00910c7f _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    15  UIKit                               0x005db19a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    16  UIKit                               0x005dc0ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    17  UIKit                               0x005afe86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x0059a18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3483f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01a341cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01a5129e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a50ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a508db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x038bc9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x038bc809 GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x0059cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  To-Do Pro Light                     0x00007d2d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x020e7725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Please, any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in what you are doing:

```
[self.searchResults removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am guessing that `searchResults` is a `NSArray` which is immutable.  Either change that to a `NSMutableArray` (not casting, actually change the object) or change your logic/UX.

For example, does it really make sense to allow a user to delete a search result?

Comment: You are right, but then how could I avoid a user to use the default swipe to left gesture and not to appear the red DELETE button? I mean only at the search results list..

Comment: There is a delegate method for that on the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol called `-[UITableViewDataSource tableView: canEditRowAtIndexPath:]`.  I would suggest reading the documentation.